# Fill combobox when selected another combobox c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to fill a combobox5 from data in the database when selected another combobox1 and this is the code i am trying right now to solve the problem.

```
void FillCombo3()
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myconnstring);
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM Section ";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlDataReader myReader;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            while (myReader.Read())
            {
                if(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "ClassName")
                {
                    comboBox5.Items.Add("SectionName");
                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error is", ex);
        }


    }
```

Comment: It is always wonderful to see 3 architectural layers mixed up in just a few lines of  code.

Comment: What is your plan with dt? And the data you read from the reader?